# Can't initialize graph on Datastax using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise-graph, dse-graph-frames

I'm trying to initialize my Datastax graph using Spark as follow :

```
val graphBuilder = spark.dseGraph("GRAPH_NAME")
```

but I have the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/bdp/graph/impl/element/vertex/id/AbstractVertexIdExternalImpl
at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrameBuilder$.apply(DseGraphFrameBuilder.scala:257)
at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.SparkSessionFunctions.dseGraph(SparkSessionFunctions.scala:20)
```

I search a dataxtax jar that contains`com/datastax/bdp/graph/impl` but I didn't find it.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what version of DSE, how do you submit application?

Comment: version Dse : 6.0.4 , i tested with 5.0.4 also

Comment: how do you submit job? via `dse spark-submit` or you're using separate spark?

Comment: i'm using a separet spark

Comment: Please show what do you link to your application (Maven/SBT/...) do you use BYOS jar, or only DseGraphFrames?

Comment: Hi Alex , after adding byos dependencies  i have a problem when i'm runing my spark jobs :18/12/07 14:12:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.SerializableSchema
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166)
Do you have any idea about this error plz ?

Comment: Just checked the BYOS, it has that class - you either don't submit job correctly, or don't link correctly

Comment: Yeh it exist  in jar file ,  after executing jobs i have this :org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.SerializableSchema
  at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166)   at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:193)     at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.DseGraphRpc.callGetSchema(DseGraphRpc.java:50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DseGraphFrames in your program running on external Spark, you need to link with so-called [BYOS](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/byosIntro.html) jar.  This could be done as following (for Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
  <artifactId>dse-byos_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And add DataStax repositories:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>DataStax-Repo</id>
      <url>https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And if you check the jar fetched from DataStax repository, it contains necessary file:

```
unzip -l dse-byos_2.11-6.0.4.jar|grep AbstractVertexIdExternalImpl
     2839  10-06-2018 15:22   com/datastax/bdp/graph/impl/element/vertex/id/AbstractVertexIdExternalImpl.class
```

Comment: it works for me , i also added  "dse-graph-frames" dependencies  i used  DseGraphFrameBuilder.dseGraph(cassandraConf.GRAPH_NAME, spark)  to get  DseGraphFrame . Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Alex , after adding byos dependencies i have a problem when i'm runing my spark jobs :18/12/07 14:12:00 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.SerializableSchema at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166) Do you have any idea about this error plz ?